# How to handle Notification click on audio_service?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to display an audio player (goto specific screen) when a user clicks on the notification panel. Currently, when the user clicks on the notification it displays a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter_media_notification 1.2.6